# gRPC: defining an rpc which returns one stream and one data

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Let's say I have a file I want to transfer using grpc and streaming,

```
service FileService {
    rpc GetFile(FileRequest) returns (stream FileResponse) {}
}

message FileRequest {
    int32 id = 1;
}

message FileResponse {
    bytes chunk = 1;
}
```

So I want client to know how many chuncks will be sent in total. This data only will be sent for once. I don't want to create a new method, but it seems like I can't add a second return value which will not be a stream. What is my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `stream` doesn't have defined length, if stream has expected length maybe it should be an `array`?

But trying to solve it using `steam` you can maybe try use `oneof` and first record of the `stream` will contain length and rest actual data

```
message FileResponse {
    oneof data {
        int32 length = 1;
        bytes chunk = 2;
    };
}
```

The issue here is that `length` can be sent also in the middle of the stream

Another way to somehow handle it is to use `optional`, then generated code should also provide another property called `HasLength`(at least C# has it like that), maybe instead of `length` in this case you can name it `remaining` and update it

```
message FileResponse {
    optional int32 length = 1;
    bytes chunk = 2;
}
```

I hope it helps